# Communication between two Dialog Fragment Android

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have one dialog fragment(`AddAlarmDialogFragment`) with a custom layout, which after click on the TextView is starting another `TimePickerFragment`.

TimePickerFragment is showing TimePickerDialog.

```
    @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),TimePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT, this, hour, minute,
            true);

}
```

So far everything is working, but I want TimePickerFragment to pass the information about picked time to the parent DialogFragment

I made TimePickerFragment implementing `TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener,` to override the callback method `onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)`.

I declared also my interface inside TimePickerFragment

```
    public interface OnTimePickedListener {
     void timePicked(int hour, int minutes);
}
```

The method `timePicked(int hour, int minutes)` is called inside `onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)`

This is the whole code of the callBack

```
        @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        OnTimePickedListener onTimePickedListener=
OnTimePickedListener)getParentFragment();
        onTimePickedListener.timePicked(hourOfDay,minute);
    }
```

And here is a problem,that I want to pass the time from `TimePickerDialog` to the `AddAlarmDialogFragment`, so the DialogFragment which launched `TimePickerFragment`

Is there any way to get the instance of this interface from the parent dialogFragment. Or maybe there is a better way to provide a communication between this two components, because for me defining `OnTimePickedListener` which has almost exactly the same method as `TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener` seem like not idea which is making code clean.

Comment: So `TimePickerFragment` launches `TimePickerDialog`, and you want some data from `TimePickerDialog` to go back to `TimePickerFragment`?

Comment: I edit my question, to make clearer. I want to pass the data to AddAlarmDialogFragment which is opening TimePickerFragment. Both of the classes are extending DialogFragment. My aim is to edit the show the time from time picker in the text view in AddAlarmDialogFragment.

Comment: Use Events for this sort of issue; Publisher/Subscriber design pattern should work; google EventBus Library for android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getParentFragment()` is not getting the parent because you're using the `FragmentManager` of the `Activity`. In order for `getParentFragment()` to work, you need to use `getChildFragmentManager()` when performing your fragment transactions.

However, for your purposes, you should just leverage the fragment tagging capability and find the fragment you're looking for:

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    Fragment fragment = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
       .findFragmentByTag(TimePickerFragment.TAG);

    if (fragment == null) {
        // the fragment we're looking for doesn't exist
        return;
    }

    try {
        OnTimePickedListener onTimePickedListener=(OnTimePickedListener)fragment;
        onTimePickedListener.timePicked(hourOfDay,minute);
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        // the fragment we're looking for doesn't implement the proper callback
        throw new ClassCastException(fragment.toString()
                + " must implement OnTimePickedListener");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if `getChildFragmentManager()` works for `DialogFragment`s, but if it does, you should totally go that route as it doesn't tightly couple components.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to communicate between different parts of the application without passing references between them all. (Decoupling)

If you think that your code will grow and you're going to have couple of components talking to each other you might want to consider a complete solution.
You can use android LocalBroadcastManager or even more recommended to use eventbus implementation to to this.
There are few alternatives for event bus.